Show all network activity in task manager
Is there a way to make the Windows 10 task manager (or the resource monitor) show network usage for ALL tasks, including the kernel?  I am trying to figure out which process / task is eating up my network bandwidth.  When I run an internet speed test in my browser (chrome), I can see the usage spike in Task Manager's Wifi graph, and I can see the usage of chrome.exe jump to the expected number in the processes tab (when I sort by network %).  That is, the usage shown in task manager roughly matches what the internet speed test reports.  No other process (as shown by task manager) has a significant % network usage.
But something is consuming a lot of network BW.  The available bandwidth on my home network is normally 60 Mbps up and down, and I can see that number when I run the speed test on other devices (e.g. my phone).  I can also see that on my Windows 10 laptop immediately after a reboot, but after some hours have gone by, the speed test will show only 20 or 30 Mbps.  So, the problem is somewhere on my laptop, but Task Manager / Resource Monitor isn't showing me the culprit.  Does somebody know how to make it show more data?
I realize this question sounds similar to others that have been asked in the past (such as How to make windows task manager to show network usage?), but those solutions didn't work for me.

You say you've tried Resource Monitor. The "Processes with Network Activity" section includes all processes, including System. So I'm not sure what else you are looking for. Also, your title doesn't quite align with the body of your question. If you could edit one or the other so they are more in alignment, it might help attract more answers.

You might look at free tools, Network Usage View (https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_usage_view.html) and Glasswire (https://www.glasswire.com) for more info.

Doug, turn that into an answer and it'll probably be a good one for this.

Windows 10 does come with a neat utility that tracks the volume of data downloaded per application since connecting to the network: under Settings > Network and Internet > Status > Data Usage. Some routers have utilities for tracking data per device as well. If you don't see anything in Resource Monitor though, then the speed difference is probably not caused by a process leeching internet. Try using different speed tests as well


Is there a way to make the Windows 10 task manager (or the resource monitor) show network usage for ALL tasks, including the kernel?

In Resource Monitor there is a section titled "Processes with Network Activity". This section displays info about all processes, including System. And the description for System is "NT Kernel & System".
That answers your question as asked.
If you are looking for other network traffic tools that might help you understand more about the traffic, try:

Settings > Network and Internet > Status > Data Usage (thanks, Cpt.Whale)
Network Usage View (thanks, DrMoishe Pippik)
Glasswire (thanks, DrMoishe Pippik)


Thanks, Doug.  You corrected a false assumption that I made.  The resource monitor does indeed show all network activity.  So, I am now going to explore the possibility that the Wifi adapter or its driver is messed up.
